# Mysql very slow query, but fast working after reboot (CPU usage 99%)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query generated ORM (Hibernate). Query is big, but after restart MySQL service it works fast (0.2 sec.). A few days later, the query is becoming slower and slower (> 1 min.). I run DESCRIBE. And I see that the query plan is different. But I do not know what the problem is and how I can remedy the situation.

Fast:

[image: Fast]

Slow:

[image: Slow]

[Generated query](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XN2NXVGRHV3lKVVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are there more data being added over time to your database?

Comment: I don't think anyone here is going to be to make a meaningful suggestion based only on this massive execution plan, not even Gordon Linoff.  Can you share the query with us?

Comment: @suguspnk Yes. But each time after the reboot performance again is good. Therefore, I do not think that the matter is in the amount of data.

Comment: Squinty little screenshots aren't helping here. What you need to do is have MySQL Workbench open and monitoring your server to find out what the issues are. "Slow" is not a diagnostic. You must look for possible causes like server load, hard disk activity, etc.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes, of course, I added query.

Comment: Couple of reasons could be number of open connections or MySQL load that might be locking your queries. When you reboot, all connections and running queries are dropped putting server to clean state. Monitor your server, mysql, any other processes running, CPU utilization, RAM utilization, etc.

Comment: Yes thanks! cpu usage is 99%. But several of such query always is running, I think this they use 99% cpu.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? And what is O/S?

Comment: @ManojKumarRai mysql version is 5.6.17. Used CentOS

Comment: One thing I had problems with in profiling some code once was that it actually got faster at some point, then slowed down on reboot.  It came down to /tmp being full, in my case when it filled the profiler stopped logging data, check as if /tmp is full it can cause problems.  Rebooting clears /tmp and so starts again.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks I'll try to clear the tmp folder  when problem is repeat. It will be strange if tmp is not cleaned as needed.

Comment: @NigelRen, i removed /tmp and /var/tmp folders but mysql server showed error. Had restart machine. Maybe it needs to be done differently?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the number of connection used in your MySQL, I have to doubt there are so many connections are opened or used that's why query execution plan was slow, but after reboot it comparatively fast..

Hop its work!

Comment: Ok, thank. I check connections count when problem is repeat. After reboot Threads_connected is 60.